# Optimal pairing of players

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have class of Player:

```
sn:"Bruce", pn:9, op:(8,)
```

where sn - name, pn - pairing number, op - opponents with which the player has already played

class have also possible to check if player can play with opponent: player.can_play(p2) - this return true when can play and false when can't.

Suppose I have such a list of players,

```
sn:"Player1", pn:1, op:(8,2), 
sn:"Player2", pn:2, op:(7,1),
sn:"Player3", pn:3, op:(6,4), 
sn:"Player4", pn:4, op:(5,3),
sn:"Player5", pn:5, op:(4,6), 
sn:"Player6", pn:6, op:(3,5),
sn:"Player7", pn:7, op:(2,8), 
sn:"Player8", pn:8, op:(1,7)
```

How can I generate pairs of players assuming they should not meet in previous rounds?
I can generate pairs but I don't know how check if this pairing is ok and how to mix players to get optimal pairing. Could you help me?

I can use itertools.combinations but I don't think this is optimal way.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by optimal pairings - do you just mean legal pairings?  You only have given other information to evaluate what is optimal. Also you have opponents listed in past games that don't exist in your dataset (0, 99, 88) - how do you plan to use that informaiton?

Comment: Anyway the best approach here would probably be to hold a `set` of all existing players, and for each player, simply subtract from this set the set of his `op` (already played against players)...

Comment: I changed players to make it easier. Let's assume there will be 150 players, for example. Will checking all possible combinations be the most optimal solution?

Comment: It is not necessary. As I said you can use a `set` of all players and know exactly the pairs instead of creating all combinations and then filtering... Using `set` operations is `O(1)` also, so that should be pretty efficient